# Dynamic data sheet combined with one static

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql

I am using a sheet in excel which pulls data out automatically SQL from a database. Fills in maybe 20 or so columns with orderinfo.

In column A i have a unique order no.

What i want to achieve is adding a column for an example C that is static. I fill in a number related to the order and i want it to stick with all the other rows connected to the orderno.

If i would create a new column right now (fill in text) and when the file updates the text will not match the correct columns, due to the file getting filled with new orderinfo.

Any help would be really appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: So basically you want to add an attribute which corresponds to the primary key (unique ID) of your 'Orders' table in your database? I may be misunderstanding you, but it's possible that your database itself isn't actually fit for purpose (is it fully normalised?). The operation you describe in your Excel file should interact with the actual database table. I'd suggest having a SQL operation which allows you to add your value for column C direct to the DB, and then retrieves the data again.

But I may just be misunderstanding. http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing manual and queried data, this can never work in the way you describe.

You would need a separate sheet where you keep your static data against an order number manually entered. Then you can produce a query that merges your manual data with the query data and displays them together.

This approach then also suggests an improvement whereby, on your manual entry page, you add one or more columns to lookup data from the query table using `vlookup` against the order number.